# Python: Checks user input guess any item

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

I am newbie, and I need help, please.  I am asking user to guess any item, if it's not correct - keeps asking. However, I am trying to do many ways but cannot get the code right. Sometimes, it's just ask 1 time and stop even if the user input is wrong; or it does not recognize the answer right or wrong and keep asking.
Thank you!

```
animal = ['bird','dog','cat','fish']
while True:
    guess = input('Guess my favorite animal: ')
    if guess == animal:
        print("You are right")
        break
    print('Try again!')
```

Comment: `if guess in animal:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work because you are comparing user input to a list.

```py
guess == animal
```

Will be evaluated as:

```
guess == ['bird','dog','cat','fish']   # Evaluates to "false"
```

Testing if an element is in a list is simple:

```
# A set of animals
animals = ['bird','dog','cat','fish']

'bird' in animals  # Returns True, because bird is in the list
>>> True

'cow' in animals   # Returns False, because cow is not in the list
>>> False
```

Assuming each 'animal' or element of the list is unique, a set is a more efficient data structure to use.

Your code then becomes:

```py
animal = {'bird','dog','cat','fish'}
while True:
    guess = input('Guess my favorite animal: ')
    if guess in animal:
        print("You are right")
        break
    print('Try again!')
```